# How To Cancel A Server Side Streaming Request if Streaming Never Starts?

Tags: c++, grpc

When using grpc async interface, server side streaming involve 3 main steps on the server side code:

1. Request - The server starts listening to a client request for the stream.
2. Writing- once step 1 associated tag is returned from the completion queue, the server may start writing to the stream via `ServerAsyncWriter::Write`.
3. Once the server finishes the stream, it call `ServerAsyncWriter::Finish`.

If I wish to cancel the RPC from the Server side, I could theoretically do that via `grpc::ServerContext::TryCancel`.
However, Calling `TryCancel` is only possible after stage 1 has finished. If, for example, a client never asks for the stream to start, then step 1 never completes. There is no way to cancel the request in this case except Shutting down the server as a whole.

I tried calling `grpc::ServerContext::TryCancel` before the streaming has even began and it causes an access violation.

So how can I cancel an RPC from the server side in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `grpc::ServerContext` instance before step 2. So it seems that you used the wrong `grpc::ServerContext` instance there. And gRPC doesn't have a way to undo the first step. (I used undo here because `cancel` verb in gRPC makes only sense when there is a corresponding request) You can shutdown the server to undo this if you want.